# AdaBoost - get prediction for the specific number of estimators

Tags: prediction, scikit-learn, adaboost

I use *AdaBoostClassifier* from *sklearn.ensemble*. I trained my model using 1000 estimators:

```
model = AdaBoostClassifier(
    base_estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 6),
    n_estimators = 1000,
    learning_rate = 0.2
)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

then using generator `model.staged_predict_proba(X_test)` I get know that the best accuracy for *X_test* data is for 814 estimators.

Now I don't want to use generator `model.staged_predict_proba(X_test)` to make prediction for new test data *X_test_2* because it is a lot of time to calculate predictions for each number of estimators (the dataset is really big). I just want to calculate predictions for model based on 814 estimators. I didn't find a way to do it. Is it possible for *AdaBoostClassifier*? I think it should be.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why would we just re-train with 814 estimators (using the full sample that is)?

Comment: @usεr11852 I don't want to re-train. I want to make predictions using first 814 cumulated estimators based on already trained model.

Comment: OK, in that case this a purely programming question. I think you should migrate it to SO.

Comment: @usεr11852 Yeap, you're right.